# Change bit value on session expire asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I'm building a chat app.But on logout button I can change bit value in database from 1 if user login to 0. But if user close the app or exit the browser without hitting logout, how can I change the bit value to 0? 
Need answer programmatically.

Comment: `Session` is going to be difficult to monitor in this scenario. You could 'refresh' the user's active status (perhaps in a field in the database) whenever they post and I guess 'expire' them if there is no activity for `n` minutes? What technology are you using? Have you seen **SignalR**? It's perfectly suited to this kind of app.

Answer (score 0):

When you close your browser, your webserver won't receive any feedback. Most browsers also do not allow you to implement javascript that does this. The only way to track this is by using something that polls your server periodically. (As @scgough put in the comments, SignalR is one of these technologies that you can use to do this.)

The downside of these techniques is that web browsers will generate web traffic to your webserver periodically to send 'heartbeat' signals, which in turn keeps the session alive for as long as the browser is open. This means this will consume a bit more web traffic and server resources.